# Chamada a métodos em classe controller (asp.net web.api) para de funcionar ao trocar nome de parâmetro

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Tenho uma dúvida no uso do asp.net web api com angularJS que segue abaixo.

Eu tenho 2 métodos na minha classe controller (ItensController.cs):

```
public void Put(int id, [FromBody]Item value)
{
}
```

e

```
[ActionName("UpdateItemFees")]
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateItemFees(int id, [FromBody]Item value)
{         
}
```

Minha chamada no client é:

```
$http.put('/api/Itens/Put/' + $scope.osID, item)
$http.post('/api/Itens/UpdateItemFees/' + $scope.osID, item)
```

Isso funciona sem problemas. O problema é quando eu mudo o nome de um parametro nestes métodos, aí, o sistema não faz mais a chamada ao método na ItensController:

```
public void Put(int osID, [FromBody]Item value)
{
}
```

e

```
[ActionName("UpdateItemFees")]
[HttpPost]
public void UpdateItemFees(int osID, [FromBody]Item value)
{         
}
```

Os erros são:

No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

```
'http://local/api/Itens/Put/3443'.
```

and

No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI

```
'http://local/api/Itens/UpdateItemFees/3443'.
```

O que tem de errado ao mudar o nome do parâmetro do método (de "id" para "osID")?

Eu tenho outros métodos na página, como o GET que estão funcionando perfeitamente, inclusive com parâmetros com nomes customizados (isso que eu acho estranho).

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente, a rota.

Normalmente, ela é configurada assim:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
     name: "DefaultApi",
     routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
     defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
   );
```

Ou seja, a rota `DefaultApi` conhece uma rota cujo próximo parâmetro seja `id`, e o *Controller* confia nisso.

Se você chamasse a requisição da seguinte forma:

```
http://local/api/Itens/Put/?osID=3443
```

Repare que vai funcionar, porque aí você força o `ModelBinder` a ler um parâmetro chamado `osID` que não necessariamente foi definido na rota.

Tem algumas maneiras de resolver. Uma é definindo uma rota que aceite `osID` como parâmetro sem precisar colocar o nome do parâmetro no endereço da requisição. A outra é usar do jeito que indiquei acima.